# Need help interpreting Java thread dump

Tags: java, ibm-mq, java-threads, jstack

An application stalls recently. There is a thread in dump looks like below. Does this mean there was a deadlock in this thread? Or this is normal state?

```
"DispatchThread: [com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.impl.RemoteSession[:/28dd1d5b][connectionId=414D5143424E535341434920202020205DD7618B2D0AD502]]" daemon prio=3 tid=0x0000000008001800 nid=0x56 in Object.wait() [0xfffffc7fde379000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (on object monitor)
        at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
        - waiting on <0xfffffc7bc3b048b8> (a com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.impl.RemoteDispatchThread$SleepingEventSync)
        at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.impl.RemoteDispatchThread.waitOnSleepingEvent(RemoteDispatchThread.java:122)
        - locked <0xfffffc7bc3b048b8> (a com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.impl.RemoteDispatchThread$SleepingEventSync)
        at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.impl.RemoteDispatchThread.sleepPhase(RemoteDispatchThread.java:605)
        at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.impl.RemoteDispatchThread.run(RemoteDispatchThread.java:359)
        ...
        at com.ibm.msg.client.commonservices.j2se.workqueue.WorkQueueManagerImplementation$ThreadPoolWorker.run(WorkQueueManagerImplementation.java:1227)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
        - None
```

The code is in MQ JMS driver which application uses. the last two methods are:

```
private void sleepPhase() {
    if (Trace.isOn) {
        Trace.entry(this, "com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.impl.RemoteDispatchThread", "sleepPhase()");
    }
    if (this.flightRecorder.isOn) {
        this.flightRecorder.entry("RemoteDispatchThread.sleepPhase");
    }
    do {
        boolean posted;
        if (posted = this.noMsgsWait != 0 ? this.waitOnSleepingEvent(this.noMsgsWait) : (this.hconnActive ? this.waitOnSleepingEvent(2000) : this.waitOnSleepingEvent(30000))) {
            if (this.flightRecorder.isOn) {
                this.flightRecorder.exit("RemoteDispatchThread.sleepPhase (posted)");
            }
            if (!Trace.isOn) break;
            Trace.data(this, "sleepPhase (return (posted))", (Object)null);
            break;
        }
        if (this.noMsgsWait != 0) {
            if (this.flightRecorder.isOn) {
                this.flightRecorder.exit("RemoteDispatchThread.sleepPhase (noMsgsWait)");
            }
            if (!Trace.isOn) break;
            Trace.data(this, "sleepPhase (return (noMsgsWait))", (Object)null);
            break;
        }
        this.hconn.requestThreadLock();
        try {
            if (this.savedDispatchSeq != this.dispatchSeq) {
                if (Trace.isOn) {
                    Trace.exit((Object)this, "com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.impl.RemoteDispatchThread", "sleepPhase()", 1);
                }
                return;
            }
            if (this.hconnActive) continue;
            if (this.flightRecorder.isOn) {
                this.flightRecorder.exit("RemoteDispatchThread.sleepPhase (hconn inactive)");
            }
            if (Trace.isOn) {
                Trace.data(this, "sleepPhase (hconn inactive)", (Object)null);
            }
            this.hconn.setDispatchThread(null);
            this.exitThread = true;
        }
        finally {
            if (Trace.isOn) {
                Trace.finallyBlock(this, "com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.impl.RemoteDispatchThread", "sleepPhase()");
            }
            this.hconn.releaseThreadLock();
            continue;
        }
        break;
    } while (true);
    if (Trace.isOn) {
        Trace.exit((Object)this, "com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.impl.RemoteDispatchThread", "sleepPhase()", 2);
    }
}


private class SleepingEventSync {
    SleepingEventSync() {
        if (Trace.isOn) {
            Trace.entry(this, "com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.impl.SleepingEventSync", "<init>()");
        }
        if (Trace.isOn) {
            Trace.exit(this, "com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.impl.SleepingEventSync", "<init>()");
        }
    }
}
```

There was a MQ upgrade recently and I copied the MQ client jars to the application.

Comment: could you include the most recent line of code (that you wrote) that causes this issue from the trace?

Comment: I posted the code of last two methods in the dump.

Comment: If you have full thread dump then look for thread that has locked `0xfffffc7bc3b048b8`. And full thread dump shows dead locks at the end.

Comment: Looks like same thread has locked `0xfffffc7bc3b048b8` two lines below.

Comment: What specific IBM MQ jar version after you using?

Comment: MQ version 9.1.0.0.      
Compilation date is: Thu Jul 05 17:40:32 EDT 2018

Comment: There is a dead lock.  Try 9.1.0.3.  Google MQC91 and download the Java-All package.

Comment: http://www.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?rs=171&uid=swg1IT27638

Comment: Does updating the jar file fix the issue?

Comment: It is waiting on an object (in a TIMED_WAIT state), so it is not a deadlock, because to wait on an object, you need to have had a lock on that object (and indeed it did as shown by the lock ids in the trace). What it means is that the object it is waiting on is not (yet) notified, so it doesn't wake up from its wait.

Comment: Thanks Josh, Mark. I tried to download the "Fix" from the IBM website, however, it is delivered as a image file mqm-U09010003.img which require special handling.

Comment: As I mentioned in my comment above,  download Java-All, it is delivered as a self extracting jar.

Comment: Different versions of the "com.ibm.mq.allclient" are available on Maven: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.ibm.mq/com.ibm.mq.allclient  Pick the version you want then download it.  Note: Since you are writing JMS code then you will also need to download the latest release (v2.0.1) of the JMS JAR file: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.jms/javax.jms-api

Comment: Hi All, the issue is resolved by using copying the code from a production environment. there is some binary or/and configuration issue. I'm still doing the analysis. But the checksum for MQ drivers were not changed between two copies.

Comment: @Mark Rotteveel. When I take a thread dump from the normal running process, the same MQ thread (DispatchThread) still has the "- locked <0xfffffc7bc3b048b8>" line is there, the "- waiting on <0xfffffc7bc3b048b8>" line does not appear.

any idea about the difference?